# WordPress: label is not working in Option page

Tags: wordpress, label, wordpress-theming

I want to add some radio buttons using following code:

```
add_settings_field(
    'video_embed', 
    'Embed YouTube/Videmo Video', 
    array( $this, 'video_embed_callback' ),
    'setting-admin',
    'field_settings'
);
```

and wrote callback function like following:

```
public function video_embed_callback()
{
    $value = isset( $this->options['is_video_embed'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['is_video_embed']) : '';
    printf('<label><input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_y" name="option_name[is_video_embed]" value="enable" '.checked( $value, 'enable', false ).' /> Enable</lable>');
    echo "<br>";
    printf('<label><input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_n" name="option_name[is_video_embed]" value="disable" '.checked( $value, 'disable', false ).' /> Disable</lable>');
}
```

Everything working, but problem is lebel is not working. When i **inspect** the page i got following structure:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">Embed YouTube/Videmo Video</th>
    <td>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_y" name="nl_option_name[is_video_embed]" value="enable">
            Enable<br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_n" name="nl_option_name[is_video_embed]" value="disable">
            Disable
            </label>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but it should be like following:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_y" name="nl_option_name[is_video_embed]" value="enable">
    Enable<br>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_n" name="nl_option_name[is_video_embed]" value="disable">
Disable
</label>
```

Please help me, I don't know what is happening :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf('<label><input type="radio" id="is_video_embed_y" name="option_name[is_video_embed]" value="enable" '.checked( $value, 'enable', false ).' /> Enable</lable>');
```

its **label** not **lable**, you have a typo in the ending label tag